# MVC 3 Razor - show modal based on an EF query

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, modal-dialog

At work I have been tasked with adding additional functionality to an existing MVC 3/Razor project.  I haven't used MVC before, but am quite versed with Web Forms.

However, I am not quite sure where to place everything I need.

When the app is first loaded, a login page appears.  When the user logs in successfully, the user sees a dashboard type page.

The new functionality is to detect whether the user has FollowUpItems with a `Due Date < Now`. If `Count > 0` then display a Modal popup with some text and a link to 'View Followup Items'.

There is already a controller and action made for viewing Followup items.  I need to display the modal, and I would like to make the modal a reuseable type of object - I am assuming/thinking a PartialView where I can pass in the name of the Controller, Action, Params for a possible `ActionLink` that I would display in the modal popup, and the message text, etc.

I need a little guidance on how to open the modal since it isn't attached to a click, but rather to whether an expression evaluates true or false, and where the best place for the pieces are.

Thanks in advance for the guidance

Comment: Do you have jQuery for this project?

Comment: Yes, I do. I can have anything I want to add.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would detect if the user has FollowUpItems in the Action that loads the dashboard page, and store that information in the ViewBag. For example,

```
public ActionResult Dashboard()
{
    ViewBag.HasFollowupItems = UserHasFollowupItems();
    return View();
}
```

In this example, `UserHasFollowupItems()` returns a string, something like 'true' or false'.

In the dashboard view, add an empty div into which the modal data will be loaded

```
<div id="followup_items"></div>
```

then add a document.ready() in the same view which defines the modal and determines if the modal should be loaded:

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    // define modal
    $("#followup_items").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 'auto',
        width: 825,
        title: 'Followup Items',
        position: [75, 75],
        modal: true,
        draggable: true,
        closeOnEscape: true,
        buttons: {
            'Close': function ()
            {
                $(this).dialog('close');
            }
        },
        close: function ()
        {            
            $('.ui-widget-content').removeClass('ui-state-error');
        },        
    });

    if(@ViewBag.HasFollowupItems == 'true')
    {
        $('#followup_items').load("/FollowupItems/Load", function (data, txtStatus, XMLHttpRequest)
        {
            $('#followup_items').dialog('open');
        }
    });
});
```

In this example `/FollowupItems/Load` is the URL to the proper controller/action that generates the data for the view. You are correct, the view for this would be a partial view, loaded into the empty followup_items div on the page.

So you can use the @ViewBag object anywhere in the view, in this case passing in your boolean indicating if the modal should be loaded/opened. I have not found a way to use ViewBag in an external javascript file, so I typically use embedded script tags in my views so I can use the ViewBag.

You could also add in the user id in the same way (`/FollowupItems/Load/@ViewBag.Userid`), or any other data the followup action needs.

Comment: Thank you so much for following up.  I'll look at this when I get home.  Looks good to me. :)